# How to join those two config parts together?

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmobar

In my xmonad config I have the following:

```
main = do 
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar -x 0 ~.config/xmobar/xmobar.config"
  xmonad $ docks defaults
```

But having problems with chrome, I need to add this:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops

main = xmonad $ ewmh def{ handleEventHook =
           handleEventHook def <+> fullscreenEventHook }
```

I am not sure how to combine those two. So to keep the xmobar config, the docks defaults and the ewmh

I tried this

```
main = do 
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar -x 0 ~.config/xmobar/xmobar.config"
  xmonad $ ewmh def{ handleEventHook =
           handleEventHook def <+> fullscreenEventHook }
```

But I need to add docks too.

UPDATE:

Thank you for your suggestion Li-yao Xia.
I tried this:

```
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar -x 0 ~/.config/xmobar/xmobar.config"
  xmonad $ docks defaults $ ewmh def{ handleEventHook =
     handleEventHook def <+> fullscreenEventHook }
```

But that gives error

```
XMonad will use ghc to recompile, because "/home/adam/.xmonad/build" does not exist.
Error detected while loading xmonad configuration file: /home/adam/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

xmonad.hs:273:12: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘XConfig
                                      (Choose Tall (Choose (Mirror Tall) Full))
                                    -> XConfig l0’
                  with actual type ‘XConfig
                                      (XMonad.Layout.LayoutModifier.ModifiedLayout
                                         AvoidStruts (Choose Tall (Choose (Mirror Tall) Full)))’
    • The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
      but its type ‘XConfig
                      (XMonad.Layout.LayoutModifier.ModifiedLayout
                         AvoidStruts (Choose Tall (Choose (Mirror Tall) Full)))’
      has none
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘docks defaults
           $ ewmh
               def
                 {handleEventHook = handleEventHook def <+> fullscreenEventHook}’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        xmonad
          $ docks defaults
              $ ewmh
                  def {handleEventHook = handleEventHook def <+> fullscreenEventHook}
    |
273 |   xmonad $ docks defaults $ ewmh def{ handleEventHook =
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...

Please check the file for errors.

xmonad: xmessage: executeFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `docks` and `ewmh` both take a config

```
docks :: XConfig a -> XConfig a
ewmh  :: XConfig a -> XConfig a
```

they are functions, that can be composed

```
  xmonad $ docks $ ewmh def{ handleEventHook =
           handleEventHook def <+> fullscreenEventHook }
```

You also appear to have a custom config `defaults :: XConfig a`, which you can probably use in place of `def` (which is the default provided by XMonad itself)

```
  xmonad $ docks $ ewmh defaults{ handleEventHook =
           handleEventHook defaults <+> fullscreenEventHook }

  -- note there are two occurrences of "defaults" here (you definitely want the first one, and the second one matters if defaults and def have different definitions of handleEventHook)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work - I updated the content

Comment: I did not write `docks defaults`

Comment: Without that, it does compile, but skips the configuration defined in the file - I need it also. Do you know how to add that part please?

Comment: You can probably replace `def` with `defaults` (see my last edit to the answer). But it was hard to tell that `defaults` was something custom because you did not show its definition, and if you did define it, `defaults` doesn't sound like a descriptive name for it (as opposed to `myConfig` for example).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I add the handleEventHook into the `defaults` definition. Then piping as per your suggestion worked, and all is working correctly!